# My updated app is rejected because it contains content that doesn't comply with the Real-Money Gambling, Games and Contests policy

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console

```
Edited
```

After submitting an update for my app on google play console, I received this message:

> After a recent review, we found that your app "MyApp" (my.app) is not
> compliant with one or more of our Developer Program Policies. See
> below for more information about your app’s status and how to correct
> the issue.
>
> **Issue with your app**
>
> Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the Real-Money
> Gambling, Games and Contests policy.
>
> **Issue details**
>
> We found an issue in the following area(s):
>
> - **App website**: Please see attached screenshot my.app-AppWebsite-85.png

[image]

- My app doesn't contain this picture above! undoubtedly, this picture is a ads because my app contains admob ads.
- On google play console in section `App content > Target audience and content` I set `Target age group` to 6-8, 9-12, 13-15, 16-17, 18 and over.
- On Google Admob in section `Blocking controls > Ad content rating` `Match account-level setting` is enabled so `PG, T & MA ads are blocked`

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: You can try updating app version and uploading the app again. This ad might not be shown again during Google play automatic testings and you'll pass the review

Comment: @VasilyKabunov How can I avoid Real-Money Gambling, Games and Contests ads in my apps?